# Can PyCharm display variable value as hexadecimal number?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm debugging a python script in PyCharm and can't find a way to display integer values as hexadecimal numbers. Is it at all possible in this IDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature (for PyCharm) is implemented and is going to be included in 2019.3 release. Ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8118

---

Update 2019.3.4

[image]

Comment: I see the issue is marked as done. However I'm in 2019.3 and I still see no way of looking at hex.

Comment: @poleguy I added a screenshot, see above.

Comment: aha... only seems to be available on int, not on any type of list or array. Not useful for any real hex-centric engineering work.

Comment: @poleguy Uh, didn't think about such usecase. One can expand a list and view a single item inside as hex though it's probably not too convenient. Please feel free to create a feature request in PyCharm's bug tracker.

Comment: It hardly seems worth it to put in the request, considering how many years it took to implement hex for a simple int type. It's open source, so if I feel it's really needed I'll code it up myself and contribute it.

Comment: Works for me but for singular iteration only. This view is reset after every local run. so if you want to watch local value within a function, you'll have to change the view every single function call. 
In that case, adding hex(value) to the debug inline watch might be more conferrable.

Answer (score 2):

As @ndclt pointed out, you can't yet, but a workaround for the time being could be using the `evaluate expression` functionality.

Say you are interested in the hex representation of `a`, you can use the [built-in function hex()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) to achieve this:

```
hex(a)
```

Putting this in the [evaluate expression dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/evaluate-expression/) would give you the hex representation string.

You can bring up that action using CTRL+F8 (Windows/Linux) or ALT+F8 (Mac).

Answer (score 1):

Yet, [you can't](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205823439-Hexadecimal-view-in-debug). There is an open [issue also concerning Pycharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-11047?p=OC-2305) if you want to follow this feature.